# Python Sys Path For Calling py File

Tags: python, csv

When I run the predict.py file alone, it finds and reads the data.csv file. but it fails by running the predict.py file from the asd.py file in another file path;

### My Files

```
-sbin
  -master
    +asd.py
-scripts
  -bash
    -dataset
      +data.csv
    +predict.py
```

### asd.py

```
import os
import sys

runPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(runPath, "../../scripts/bash"))

from predict import pred
pred().main()
```

### predict.py

```
import pandas as pd
class pred:
    def main(self):
       data = pd.read_csv('dataset/data.csv', sep=';')
```

Could the reason for this error be caused by changing the path of operation? Or I didn't get it because of another mistake.

### Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'dataset/data.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: The sys path has your scripts folder so you can import stuff from predict.py, but when you call that code, it runs from the path of the calling script. Just declare your current working directory in predict.py and instead of using relative paths, use os.path.join on your cwd and your relative path of dataset/data.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longer answer on the comment above:
This happens because although you appended the scripts folder to your sys path in order to import stuff from predict.py, whenever you call that code inside asd.py, it will run from the calling script's (asd.py) current working directory.

What that means for you is that the relative path dataset/dataset.csv does not exist in the current working directory of asd.py (sbin/master) and consequently the code will raise a FileNotFound exception.

The way to fix this and be able to run your code from anywhere, would be to give predict.py the absolute path of your dataset file.

To do that in a way that is not hardcoded, I would do what you did to get your runPath, namely get the absolute path of your predict.py file inside a varible and use os.path.join to join that to the dataset file. That way you can always be sure the dataset file will be found by whatever calling script uses the code in predict.py.

Example below:

**predict.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
class pred:
    def main(self):
    data_fullpath = os.path.join(current_dir, 'dataset/dataset.csv')
    data = pd.read_csv(data_fullpath, sep=';')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use absolute path, instead of relative path

Answer (score 0):

sys.path documentations says:

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules

So I would not expect that relative paths starts from the path you set in asd.py
The script is trying to open dataset/data.csv starting from current folder where the script was started.

In your case I would try to pass that path somehow to the second script.